# CharacterController can climb jump on slightly tilted walls

Tags: unity-game-engine, character

I have a issue with the CharacterController component being able to climb on slightly tilted walls. The bottom part is able to stand on the wall, which makes it possible to jump again. Any advice tackeling this kind of behaviour? [Here is an example gif of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djYta.jpg)

Comment: Does the CharacterController have a capsule collider? The rounded edge along the bottom allows for climbing like that.

Comment: In the meantime I figured it had something to do with the skin width being to thin. The docs helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

It had something to do with the skinwidth being to thin.

> Two colliders can penetrate each other as deep as their Skin Width. Larger Skin Widths reduce jitter. Low Skin Width can cause the character to get stuck. A good setting is to make this value 10% of the Radius.

Retaining this value (10%) solved the issue for me.